# How to write a method searching for a String in a text file and returning the int value after it?

Tags: java, file, text

What I need is a Java method searching in text file for a specific String and returning the int value after this String. How can I seperate the read line from the text file to. My text file looks like that:

```
namea 80
nameb 50
namec 200
named 3400
```

It should be possible that the text file has some more lines.

My method looks like this for now:

```
public int readfile(String searchedString, File txtfile){
int ret = 0;

        try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(txtfile));

        String line = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.startsWith(searchedString + " ")) {
                
                ret = Integer.parseInt(//the number of the line);
            }
        }

        br.close();
        System.out.println(ret);

        } catch (IOException ex) {
          
        }
     return ret;

}
```

Comment: why don't you show us the code that you tried and let us know what is the problem. I don't think there will be anyone who will do work for you.

Comment: For everyone: I do not need this for any homework! I also searched the web for possible solutions first, but I did not find a solution how to seperate the line for example. I am quite Java beginner and even don't know how to make the method of Akiner Alkan work, because I can't do anything with the error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public int readfile(String searchedString, File txtfile){
int ret = 0;

        try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(txtfile));

        String line = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.startsWith(searchedString + " ")) {
                String[] strArr = line.split(" ");
                int item = strArr.length - 1;
                ret = Integer.parseInt(strArr[item]);
            }
        }

        br.close();
        System.out.println(ret);

        } catch (IOException ex) {
           //handle it
        }
     return ret;
}
```